# Route the audio from one app to the left channel and that from another app to the right channel

Tags: audio

I play a lot of live sound. I use one device for playing a metronome and another device for playing a backing track. I would love to use one device to play both.

Is there a way I can pan the audio from one app 100% to the left, and another app 100% to the right? I could then use a 1/8" stereo to 1/4" dual mono cable to run left and right as two separate instruments.

Comment: Hey people, this isn't a recommendation question, it's a "how do I solve this problem" question. Don't vote to close it as a recommendation question.

Comment: @DanHulme Can't you clear the CVs? Even if not, you can close and the immediately reopen it (but that'd be kind of abuse to the system).

Comment: @iBug As you say, it would be an abuse of the system. The close votes will expire after a few days.

Comment: @DanHulme Yep. Just wait for 4d since last CV. Hope the review item is invalidated already.

Comment: I'd say the title is what attracted the close votes. I just re-worded it so it looks on-topic.

Comment: Thanks for helping to keep the question alive. I appreciate it!

Comment: @DanHulme It just happened on MSE where a gold tag badge owner used his dupehammer to clear the pending CVs. So it doesn't look so abusive to the system.